# Comparing one object containing array of objects with simple array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am using Nodejs and have one object containing an array of object (result of an API request) and one simple array of values.

They look like this :

```
// Object > Array > Objects (retrieved from an API request) :
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Jimmy"
        },
        {
            "id": 825,
            "name": "Billy"
        },
    ]
}

// Simple array :
[1, 825, …]
```

How can I compare the object containing the array of objects with the simple array ?

What I am looking for is, get the IDs from the simple array and compare them to the other "complex" object to retrieve the `name` property with the corresponding IDs in the simple array and the other object property `id`, then store the result in an array of objects.

Simply put, I would like to have this result :

```
[
    { id: 1, name: "Jimmy" },
    { id: 825, name: "Billy" }
]
```

As the "complex" object is retrieved from an API request, I tried the following :

```
const ids = await axios.get(/* API CALL */);

for (let i in ids.data) {
    ids.data[i].map(el => console.log(el.name));
}
```

But this gives me an error saying I can not `map` `ids.data[i]`, even tho when I `console.log(ids.data[i])`, I get to the inner array from the initial object.

I also tried directly using `.map()` without the `for ... in` loop but this doesn't do the trick  either. Also tried `reduce` but with same results.

How should I approach this ? Note that the response from the API is one object containing one array containing thousands of object.

Thank you very much

Comment: `ids.data[i]` should be a single object from `data` right? have you tried just replacing outer for with `ids.data.map`

Answer (score -1):

Just use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and if the `id` exist in `simpleArray` then push it into `acc`

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Jimmy",
    },
    {
      id: 825,
      name: "Billy",
    },
  ],
};

const simpleArray = [1, 825, 419];

const result = obj.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, name } = curr;
  const isExist = simpleArray.includes(id);
  if (isExist) acc.push({ id, name });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use another way around also i.e. go one by one in `simpleArray` and form the required array comparing the `id` in `obj`.

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Jimmy",
    },
    {
      id: 825,
      name: "Billy",
    },
  ],
};

const simpleArray = [1, 825, 419];

const result = simpleArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const elementInObject = obj.data.find((o) => o.id === curr);
  if (elementInObject) acc.push(elementInObject);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which one would you say give the best performances ? As `obj` can have +5000 objects in the `data` array it contains. Thanks

Comment: Performance of both are comparatively same. There is not much difference. So choose one.

Answer (score -1):

Here two different one-line methods.

```js
const result = {

      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Jimmy"
        },
        {
          id: 825,
          name: "Billy"
        }
      ]
    };
    
    const ids = [1, 825, 12, 'xx'];
    
    let output = result.data.filter((obj) => ids.includes(obj.id));
    console.log(output);
    
    output = ids.map((id) => result.data.find((o) => o.id === id));    
    console.log(output.filter(obj=>obj !== undefined));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, isn't using `reduce` as shown in the answer below faster in term of performances ? As the object can contain +5000 entries with lots of properties in the `data` array.

Comment: I really don't see any performance issue in my answer. Can you provide more details?

Comment: My bad, I thought it was a O(n^2) operation but after checking out seems like its not. Thanks !